# Can i create different random numbers in one for loop in java

Tags: java, for-loop, random

so i am running a for loop, and inside that for loop i have a int which made to be a random int. So my question is can i create a different random number for each time the loop runs. Right now i can create a random number but that random number is the same for the entire for loop.
        Here is a sample of the code that i have written. If anyone can help, that would be much appreciated :)

```
for(int p=0;p<5;p++)
    {
        a=(int)Math.random()*8;
        Asteroid.add(new MovingPic(rock,50,p*a+1,p*50,1,1));
    }
```

a is an int initialized outside of the method in the global space.
So if a was randomized for each time the loop runs then the (p*a+1) would have a different value each time which is what i am trying to do but cant figure out how to.

Comment: `a = (int) (Math.random() * 8);` Order of operations matters a great deal here. Use parenthesis.

Comment: Recommended option is use, `Random.nextInt(8);`

https://kasadara.com/p/604327ad-c65e-4990-92ac-111ac96d9b07